# Resolution should not happen via injection container error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I have an EJB3 project to be deployed on JBoss 5.1.0 GA. I have Stateless EJBs being injected into other Stateless beans and Servlets.

I'm using the @EJB annotation without any parameters to inject the EJB beans, (i have a test project just to simulate the injection, which works).

When i try deploying i get the error below.

```
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resolution should not happen via injection container"
```

I have searched but can't seem to find/pinpoint the cause of the error.

**Update: 1**

Both the EJB jar and WAR are deployed in the same EAR. I'm using the JEE5 archtype, http://code.google.com/p/javaee5-maven-archetype/ to create both the main project and test. The default code generated by the archtype works, and there is no need to specify the JNDI name in the @EJB injection.

**Update: 2**
The full deployment stacktrace, http://pastebin.com/CknXie13

Comment: `The default code generated by the archtype works, and there is no need to specify the JNDI name in the @EJB` What did you add then? Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: I have a abstract DAO in which i inject the persistence context using the `@PersistenceContext`. The base DAO is extended by all DAO implementation. Of interest can i inject `@PersistenceContext` in an unmanaged bean?

Comment: `Of interest can I inject @PersistenceContext in an unmanaged bean?` No, injection can't occur since the class is unmanaged.

Comment: Please not that I still think a stacktrace and more details about the part that "isn't working" would help readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known Issue;

http://community.jboss.org/message/8196#8196

https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6332

Answer (score 4):

Here's an oft overlooked gotcha: Make sure that you use the name of the Local Interface and not the implementation when declaring the class type of the EJB in the servlet or web service. So, the mappedName in JBOSS will point to the jndi binding for the implementation while the class type in the declaration will point to the interface.  For example:

```java
@EJB(mappedName="Foo/EmployeeManagerBean/local")
EmployeeManagerLocal manager;
```

Gotcha #2: Make sure that you are compiling with Java 1.6 or higher.  This can be tricky in Eclipse.  You have to check three places in Project->Properties to make sure: Project Facets, compiler compliance settings, and the build path.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mappedName attribute of @EJB annotation, while injecting into the servlet

The attribute should contain the jndi name of the ejb.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your **web.xml** version. Version 2.4 or earlier does not support dependency injection.

Here is the sample excerpt of ***version="2.5"***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Are you putting your servlet in .WAR file? Put your servlet in .WAR file and your bean in .JAR file. Create and ear file and then deploy it